# change column backcolor to default in C# Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `Datagridview` with some colmns and some data. Now when I click on a button it changes into Editmode, where the User can change data in some columns.

The Datagridview itself has alternating row backcolors, but in editmode the editable columns are completely white. To ahieve this I use the following:

`column1.CellTemplate.Style.BackColor = Color.White;`

Now when the User finishes editing, the rows have to become like in the beginning. Can someone show me some code how to change the column completely back to default, with alternating row backcolors.
Some Info: I set the colors in the designer and not in code, so I don't even know how to set alternating backcolor anyway, I started C# only 2 months ago.

Maybe the solution is very simple, but I have no idea...

Comment: Are you rebinding the grid at the end of the update ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved: I just set the Style to the style of a column that was not changed:

`Column1.CellTemplate.Style = Column2.CellTemplate.Style;`

Column 2 was not changed, so in my case this works.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you set the alternating row in designer at the first place. And after clicking a button, editing is possible, and the cell style is changed? Well, in my opinion by this code, you break the alternate coloring.

Datagrid provides `CellEndEdit` event, so I  would suggest you to register to this event and after the event is fired, just set the alternate row style in your code behind. You will find more on this topic [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txth0a6h.aspx).

Other options might be registering to the `EditModeChanged` event and then checking if the property `EditMode` has the value you demmand. There is more choices. But I'd go with the first one. Does this solve your issue?